# I deleted the version-number of my project. How can I open the project properties now?

Tags: java, netbeans

I deleted the version-number of my project and can't open the properties of the project to fix the problem...

I don't know what to do since I can't open anything now.

[image]

When I try to open properties of my project:

[image]

When I click yes on the properties pop-up-Window:

[image]

Comment: Is this from a Maven-based project? If so, then the missing data is probably in the project's `pom.xml` file. Open that file with a text editor such as Notepad++, and add the missing value. Something like `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`, I would guess. If that does not help, we need more info.

Comment: Create a new project, close Netbeans, and copy your source code project files from the old project structure to the new project structure using the operating system copy and paste.